# In the figure $\Delta ABC$ and $\Delta DEF$ are both equilateral and $AB = 8$ cm, $DE = 3$ cm.

Tags: geometry, triangles, problem-solving

> In the figure $\Delta ABC$ and $\Delta DEF$ are both equilateral and $AB = 8$ cm, $DE = 3$ cm. Find the possible value of $AD + BE + CF$ from the options. 
> $(1)$ $6.9$ cm 
> $(2)$ $7.1$ cm 
> $(3)$ $5.2$ cm 
> $(4)$ $8.3$ cm

**What I Tried**: Here is the picture :-

[image]

I think applying Triangle Inequality can just solve the problem. 
We notice that :- $$BE + AE > AB$$
$$\rightarrow BE + AD + 3 > 8$$
$$\rightarrow BE + AD > 5$$
Similarly we get that $AD + FC > 5$ , and $FC + EB > 5$ . 
Adding all these up, we get that $$2(AD + BE + CF) > 15$$
$$\rightarrow AD + BE + CF > 7.5$$
So according to me, the correct option should be $(4)$ .

Am I right? Because I doubt that a question like this shouldn't be that easy. I just need to confirm this.

Comment: Yes, it is that easy.

Comment: Ok thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have done is correct, you have ruled out answers $1, 2$ and $3$.
However, the question is broken, the $4^{th}$ answer $8.3\,$cm is also wrong.

Let $a = AD$, $b = BE$ and $c = CF$, we have $AE = a + 3$, $BF = b+3$ and $CD = c+3$.

Consider $\triangle ABE$, Since $\angle BEA$ is an exterior angle for $\triangle DEF$, it equals to $120^\circ$.
This implies

$$\begin{align} & 8^2 = AB^2 = BE^2 + EA^2 - 2\cos(120^\circ)(BE)(EA)\\
\iff & 8^2 = b^2 + (a+3)^2 + b(a+3)\\
\iff  & a^2 + ab + b^2 + 6a + 3b = 8^2 - 3^2 = 55\\
\iff  & (a^2 + ab + b^2) + \frac92(a+b) + \frac32(a-b) = 55\end{align}$$
Multiply both sides by $a-b$, we have
$$(a^3 - b^3) + \frac92(a^2-b^2) + \frac32(a-b)^2 = 55(a-b)$$
We have two similar equalities from $\triangle BCF$ and $\triangle CAD$.
$$(b^3 - c^3) + \frac92(b^2-c^2) + \frac32(b-c)^2 = 55(b-c)$$
$$(c^3 - b^3) + \frac92(c^2-b^2) + \frac32(c-a)^2 = 55(c-a)$$
"Summing" these $3$ equalities leads to
$$\frac32((a-b)^2 + (b-c)^2 + (c-a)^2) = 0\quad\iff\quad a = b = c$$

So $AD + BE + CF = a + b + c = 3a$ and $a$ is a root of the quadratic equation

$$8^2 = a^2 + (a+3)^2 + a(a+3) \iff 3a^2 + 9a - 55 = 0$$
This quadratic equation has only one positive root
$\frac{\sqrt{741}-9}{6}$. So the correct answer is
$$\frac{\sqrt{741}-9}{2} \approx 9.1106575888162{\,\rm cm}$$

Comment: Wow, didn't know the question was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Let $AD=x$, $BE=y$ and $CF=z$.

Thus, by law of cosines we obtain the following system:
$$x^2+(z+3)^2+x(z+3)=64,$$$$y^2+(x+3)^2+y(x+3)=64$$ and $$z^2+(y+3)^2+z(y+3)=64,$$ which gives $$x=y=z=\frac{\sqrt{741}-9}{6}$$ and $$x+y+z=\frac{\sqrt{741}-9}{2}\approx9.11...$$

The system we can solve by the following way.

Let $x-y=u$, $y-z=v$ and $z-x=w$.

Thus, $u+v+w=0$.

Now, the first and the second equations give:
$$v(x+y+z)=3u+6w$$ and from the first and the third equations we obtain:
$$u(x+y+z)=3w+6v.$$
Now, if $u=0$, so $u=v=w=0$, which gives $x=y=z$ and we obtain the previous solution.

Let $uvw\neq0$.

Thus, $$\frac{u}{v}=\frac{w+2v}{u+2w}$$ or
$$\frac{u}{v}=\frac{u-v}{u+2v}$$ or
$$u^2+uv+v^2=0$$ or
$$\left(u+\frac{v}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3}{4}v^2=0,$$ which is impossible.

Thanks to  Christian Blatter, we can prove that $x=y=z$ also by the following way.
$$\measuredangle BAE=60^{\circ}-\measuredangle DAE=60^{\circ}-(\measuredangle EDF-\measuredangle DCA)=\measuredangle DCA,$$
which says $$\Delta ABE\cong\Delta CAD,$$ which gives $y=z$.

By the same way we obtain $x=y$.

Comment: It is obvious that $x=y=z$, since the angles of the three drawn lines with the sides of the large triangle have to be equal in order to make the inner triangle equilateral. It follows that the simpler and (upon your comment) deleted answer by @NgChungTak is correct.

Comment: @Christian Blatter  We need to prove it. Without this proof it's nothing. I agree that your proof of this statement is much more better than mine.